# Linq to SQL is 3x faster than Linq to Entity

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I am trying to execute the `Linq to Entity` query on `EF Core 3.1.1` and it is `3X slower` than executing the same query on Linqpad using `Linq to SQL` provider.

```
  var startDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 01, 18, 0, 0, 0);
  var endDateTime = new DateTime(2020, 02, 26, 0, 0, 0);

    var logs = _db.Logs
                .Where(w => w.UserId == 10 && w.DateStamp >= startDateTime && w.DateStamp <= endDateTime)
                .GroupBy(g => new
                {
                    g.DateStamp.Date,
                    g.Result
                }).Select(s => new
                {
                    s.Key.Date,
                    s.Key.Result,
                    Conversions = s.Count(),
                    Cost = s.Sum(sum => sum.ConversionCost)
                }).ToList();
```

I have checked the SQL which both providers generate and I would say Linq to Entity do better job writing queries.

Linq to Entity

```
-- Region Parameters
-- @__startDateTime_0='2020-01-01T00:00:00', @__endDateTime_1='2020-02-26T00:00:00'
-- EndRegion
SELECT CONVERT(date, [l].[DateStamp]) AS [Date], [l].[Result], COUNT(*) AS [Conversions], SUM([l].[ConversionCost]) AS [Cost]
FROM [Log] AS [l]
WHERE (([l].[UserId] = 10) AND ([l].[DateStamp] >= @__startDateTime_0)) AND ([l].[DateStamp] <= @__endDateTime_1)
GROUP BY CONVERT(date, [l].[DateStamp]), [l].[Result]
```

Linq To SQL

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p0 Int = 10
DECLARE @p1 DateTime = '2020-01-01 00:00:00.000'
DECLARE @p2 DateTime = '2020-02-26 00:00:00.000'
-- EndRegion
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Conversions], SUM([t1].[ConversionCost]) AS [Cost], [t1].[value] AS [Date], [t1].[Result]
FROM (
    SELECT CONVERT(DATE, [t0].[DateStamp]) AS [value], [t0].[Result], [t0].[UserId], [t0].[DateStamp], [t0].[ConversionCost]
    FROM [Log] AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE ([t1].[UserId] = @p0) AND ([t1].[DateStamp] >= @p1) AND ([t1].[DateStamp] <= @p2)
GROUP BY [t1].[value], [t1].[Result]
```

Pure SQL which I wrote by myself.

```
SELECT
CONVERT(DATE, log.DateStamp),
log.Result,
Count(*),
Sum(log.ConversionCost)
FROM
log
Where UserId= 10 AND  DateStamp >= '2020-01-01' AND DateStamp <= '2020-02-26'
GROUP BY
log.Result,
CONVERT(DATE, log.DateStamp)
```

So as you may find Pure SQL and Linq to Entity are very similar SQLs and Linq to SQL produce a little bit different version of SQL. Unfortunately, Linq to Entity query execution takes about 3 times slower than others two.

My EF Core connection string

```
data source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;initial catalog=x-test;user id=x-v2;password=x72-;connection timeout=600
```

What is the reason for that?

PS. I have tried to execute SQL using Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated and it gave perfect performance similar to Linq to SQL, but why Linq to Entity failing?

Comment: Are the sizes of the database the same?  The larger the database the more hash lookup that are needed [LOG2(N)]  Try without LIST() and see if it makes a differences.

Comment: @jdweng The database is the same and what do you mean without List? I use.ToList(); to execute Linq to Entity query.

Comment: @jdweng These are talking to the same database, please read the question properly. This is all about the differences between libraries.

Comment: @Tomas There's not a lot we can do here to help. If you're sure the speeds are so different, then you might be better opening an issue on the EF Core GitHub repo.

Comment: @DavidG The EF Core does some kind of magic when querying entities using SQL. If I execute SQL using direct sql command Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated I get perfect performance.

Comment: That's why I'm saying you likely need to open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: Have fun with that - it likely gets either ignored or you get a "planned for efcore 5" which then is delayed. the fact that EfCore is not super efficient in parts is well known and documented. The SQL is particularly ugly at times - and some of those times are being worked on. If you do a search on their github you will find a lot of open issues around the generated sql being too complicated.

Comment: @TomTom But this doesn't look to be an SQL generation issue, so it has a higher chance to be fixed. However, I think this needs to be profiled to see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @TomTom If you look at SQL which EF Core generated it looks very well written as I wrote and I know SQL pretty good. So the issue is not in translation from LinqEntities to SQL

Comment: I am not sure whether sql has a higher chance or not to be fixed - there are even in the current nightly build a TON of scenarios where you either get invalid sql, or get plain our wrong sql (i.e. sql that is technically correct, but does just not reflect the LINQ side at all - I just rewrote a dozen queris because context.table.where().select(x=>x.navproperty).Count() would just forget the navproperty and count the table). I am not sure about what they consider critical at this point - and most things are "ok, next major release in half a year" to be promptly rescheduled before release.

Comment: @Tomas I agree in this case - so then it must be somewhere in the higher efcore functions. Upgrade to the nightly builds and check whether it is already fixed.

Comment: Parameter `@p0` is missing in "fast" queries. Are you sure you use the same LINQ query in EF Core, i.e. `w.UserId == 10` and not `w.UserId == userId` where `userId` is variable? Because subquery shouldn't be an issue with SqlServer, but parameter sniffing is.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh good spot, but I would have assumed the perf issue would have been the other way round in that case. Could be an indication that both queries aren't the same though.

Comment: @IvanStoev sorry but I do not understand what you want to point out? Could you explain more detailed?

Comment: That was my impression too, but LINQ-to-SQL always converts such values into  parameters. But yes, it could be a reason that LtS is faster. Try the EF query with a variable: `w.UserId == userId`.

Comment: @GertArnold I have tried to take out 10 and put as a parameter but that does not make any speed improvements.

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at LinqToSql generated query when talking about EF Core. So EF Core is almost the same as your "hand written" except that dates are parameters, so that might be casuing the difference between the two. But I see no logical reason LinqToSql query to be faster than EF Core query.

Comment: I think I have found where is an issue if I remove querying by Date and leave the only query by UserId the problem with performance goes away. It seems to filter by DateTime slows down Linq to Entity.